# How to add ranges in histogram?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram

I have a column o values named `exceeded_amount` and I would like to plot it as a histogram. The way I do it, the plot is not legible.
How could I group the values in bins in different ranges? For example  1-100, 101-500, 501-20000 ?
Alternatively, please advise what is the best way to visualize `exceeded_amount` column.

`tr['exceeded_amount'].plot()`

[image]

**UPDATE as per  JohanC**
However, I'd like to have specific range amounts shown on the axes rather than 10^2, 10^3...etc.

```
ax = sns.boxenplot(x=tr['exceeded_amount'])  ax.set_xscale('log')
```

[image]

**What I want?**
[image]

> [19.0,
> 193.0,
> 4928.0,
> 1956.0,
> 171.0,
> 163.7,
> 231.0,
> 5.0,
> 878.5,
> 190.46,
> 89.0,
> 4.0,
> 35.0,
> 393.0,
> 171.0,
> 546.0,
> 99.98,
> 93.36,
> 0.82,
> 419.14,
> 181.0,
> 42.27,
> 2807.0,
> 116.0,
> 1199.0,
> 16.0,
> 128.0,
> 412.0,
> 100.0,
> 1070.4,
> 461.0,
> 377.0,
> 266.0,
> 930.0,
> 625.99,
> 237.5,
> 157.67,
> 58.0,
> 870.88,
> 329.5,
> 1418.0,
> 391.0,
> 329.0,
> 182.81,
> 329.5,
> 98.0,
> 211.0,
> 1.0,
> 557.0,
> 1284.04,
> 131.0,
> 113.33,
> 64.0,
> 46.66,
> 598.48,
> 149.0,
> 561.0,
> 14.83,
> 209.0,
> 454.7,
> 273.33,
> 21.0,
> 724.0,
> 2226.0,
> 209.0,
> 23.0,
> 853.56,
> 89.0,
> 63.25,
> 28.0,
> 41.0,
> 303.5,
> 103.82,
> 162.01,
> 1763.0,
> 8.0,
> 2359.0,
> 1171.0,
> 194.68,
> 1031.0,
> 362.0,
> 333.0,
> 312.0,
> 854.65,
> 630.0,
> 833.0,
> 691.0,
> 227.0,
> 139.47,
> 277.56,
> 1642.0,
> 27.0,
> 166.0,
> 931.0,
> 968.7,
> 27.33,
> 338.0,
> 201.0,
> 77.0,
> 7547.04,
> 0.49,
> 568.0,
> 307.07,
> 203.0,
> 167.56,
> 1138.78,
> 111.0,
> 51.0,
> 423.0,
> 504.62,
> 353.97,
> 51.0,
> 416.0,
> 68.05,
> 16.0,
> 7.39,
> 631.0,
> 551.0,
> 596.0,
> 89.63,
> 777.0,
> 207.0,
> 167.56,
> 246.0,
> 503.99,
> 22.0,
> 65.79,
> 21.0,
> 747.0,
> 5058.26,
> 1673.0,
> 275.92,
> 108.66,
> 99.5,
> 893.0,
> 67.0,
> 49.0,
> 663.0,
> 72.6,
> 1824.66,
> 127.0,
> 239.71,
> 1306.0,
> 815.62,
> 100.88,
> 253.0,
> 636.0,
> 600.5,
> 321.0,
> 111.0,
> 545.3,
> 312.0,
> 17.0,
> 343.61,
> 5933.0,
> 310.0,
> 356.0,
> 284.0,
> 139.0,
> 877.0,
> 48.95,
> 715.0,
> 126.33,
> 1275.0,
> 149.0,
> 8.99,
> 71.0,
> 241.0,
> 116.0,
> 225.0,
> 882.07,
> 81.0,
> 121.0,
> 53.93,
> 496.0,
> 2636.85,
> 71.0,
> 81.0,
> 8222.0,
> 52.33,
> 114.0,
> 437.0,
> 95.0,
> 28967.0,
> 142.0,
> 1.0,
> 1271.2,
> 683.76,
> 184.0,
> 220.4,
> 182.0,
> 618.0,
> 119.67,
> 661.85,
> 71.0,
> 22.37,
> 570.4,
> 388.88,
> 113.0,
> 290.0,
> 137.03,
> 3879.0,
> 619.0,
> 720.45,
> 961.5,
> 11.0,
> 101.0,
> 14.0,
> 1189.0,
> 1038.0,
> 246.0,
> 422.0,
> 153.4,
> 6999.4,
> 288.4,
> 707.28,
> 22681.0,
> 698.0,
> 305.0,
> 1097.0,
> 91.0,
> 147.0,
> 4793.26,
> 26.0,
> 309.0,
> 37.66,
> 59.2,
> 422.0,
> 417.13,
> 344.99,
> 29.0,
> 437.0,
> 545.0,
> 695.0,
> 39.66,
> 380.0,
> 709.1,
> 291.0,
> 1596.0,
> 920753.0,
> 115.68,
> 145.19,
> 81.0,
> 764.0,
> 751.63,
> 766.93,
> 2141.0,
> 327.0,
> 1358.3,
> 381.0,
> 115.0,
> 116.0,
> 571.0,
> 84.0,
> 697.0,
> 33.0,
> 1589.0,
> 123.05,
> 11.5,
> 1297.0,
> 71.0,
> 427.99,
> 63.0,
> 153.99,
> 197.99,
> 168.99,
> 1271.2,
> 30.0,
> 671.0,
> 582.33,
> 445.08,
> 378.0,
> 114.5,
> 512.0,
> 739.5,
> 411.0,
> 58.0,
> 1263.0,
> 436.69,
> 26.53,
> 14467.99,
> 1.0,
> 1659.82,
> 50.0,
> 103.07,
> 364.0,
> 191.2,
> 761.0,
> 225.0,
> 645.0,
> 129.0,
> 185.0,
> 22.44,
> 292.06,
> 342.4,
> 3347.0,
> 76.0,
> 217.5,
> 870.99,
> 54.0,
> 1218.0,
> 210.51,
> 111.0,
> 252.0,
> 1597.4,
> 123.08,
> 556.0,
> 148.0,
> 131.0,
> 356.0,
> 178.12,
> 99341.0,
> 422.0,
> 163.0,
> 551.0,
> 1992.0,
> 176.0,
> 366.0,
> 263.0,
> 156.0,
> 213.0,
> 177.0,
> 1095.38,
> 83.0,
> 375.32,
> 750.0,
> 203.66,
> 554.0,
> 201.72,
> 225.0,
> 267.0,
> 637.95,
> 89.0,
> 76.0,
> 189.48,
> 1072.21,
> 13.0,
> 284.0,
> 86.0,
> 336.99,
> 33.53,
> 117.66,
> 100.99,
> 854.0,
> 2985.95,
> 157.99,
> 5.01,
> 322.0,
> 51.0,
> 408.0,
> 1331.0,
> 312.0,
> 281.0,
> 296.18,
> 287.0,
> 197.0,
> 557.08,
> 141.0,
> 556.0,
> 16.8,
> 1511.36,
> 27.35,
> 225.0,
> 841.0,
> 380.0,
> 1211.1,
> 1068.11,
> 529.31,
> 4372.0,
> 46.0,
> 181.0,
> 225.0,
> 135.0,
> 1655.66,
> 3865.0,
> 172.0,
> 286.0,
> 143.0,
> 1391.0,
> 65.0,
> 76.0,
> 1316.0,
> 2419.0,
> 893.0,
> 165.0,
> 196.0,
> 15.99,
> 537.27,
> 38.0,
> 51.0,
> 380.0,
> 265.0,
> 341.0,
> 276.38,
> 135.0,
> 716.0,
> 4915.0,
> 59.0,
> 130.0,
> 557.08,
> 3178.0,
> 1043.8,
> 473.0,
> 1938.99,
> 486.0,
> 2272.0,
> 61.0,
> 141.27,
> 312.0,
> 252.0,
> 79.0,
> 441.0,
> 21.0,
> 71.18,
> 44.0,
> 113.0,
> 2294.0,
> 1259.0,
> 120.08,
> 881.0,
> 280.39,
> 6.0,
> 18.0,
> 42.0,
> 209.0,
> 462.0,
> 152.0,
> 301.0,
> 244.0,
> 1110.0,
> 149.0,
> 877.0,
> 711.0,
> 1978.0,
> 184.95,
> 666.0,
> 322.0,
> 205.0,
> 309.0,
> 476.0,
> 3178.0,
> 1328.0,
> 428.0,
> 183.51,
> 63.0,
> 684.0,
> 254.42,
> 354.0,
> 116.0,
> 135.0,
> 144.67,
> 31.0,
> 136.0,
> 361.0,
> 272.09,
> 737.0,
> 3347.0,
> 363.74,
> 506.0,
> 209.99,
> 4827.0,
> 545.0,
> 412.0,
> 1636.0,
> 96.0,
> 238.0,
> 422.0,
> 109.0,
> 44.0,
> 287.0,
> 327.99,
> 349.19,
> 28.99,
> 279.0,
> 181.0,
> 629.0,
> 137.75,
> 71.0,
> 2357.0,
> 493.0,
> 340.0,
> 177.16,
> 71.2,
> 4819.74,
> 22.0,
> 71.0,
> 73.73,
> 343.0,
> 121.0,
> 2272.0,
> 201.56,
> 1831.0,
> 158.98,
> 493.0,
> 576.8,
> 260.97,
> 847.0,
> 73.0,
> 5.0,
> 251.0,
> 207.0,
> 174.0,
> 82.86,
> 131.0,
> 1053.0,
> 353.0,
> 101.0,
> 854.0,
> 259.77,
> 12.37,
> 385.0,
> 9.27,
> 286.0,
> 85.0,
> 98.14,
> 21.0,
> 31.0,
> 71.0,
> 178.0,
> 63.0,
> 517.38,
> 118.0,
> 2350.0,
> 143.0,
> 88.0,
> 61.0,
> 297.0,
> 64.15,
> 20.56,
> 117.0,
> 189.0,
> 177.0,
> 630.0,
> 2997.0,
> 9961.0,
> 236.0,
> 240.0,
> 459.99,
> 3.0,
> 608.0,
> 341.0,
> 11.0,
> 1052.0,
> 42.0,
> 341.0,
> 21.0,
> 395.0,
> 575.0,
> 635.99,
> 539.83,
> 30.0,
> 570.0,
> 75.0,
> 503.99,
> 3774.0,
> 446.0,
> 87.0,
> 113.66,
> 217.5,
> 489.0,
> 41.0,
> 626.99,
> 461.0,
> 514.88,
> 813.99,
> 43.62,
> 1663.0,
> 96.0,
> 276.06,
> 73.75,
> 302.0,
> 68.0,
> 651.0,
> 25.0,
> 34.0]

Comment: Have you tried using a logorithimic y scale? That works best when your data covers a lot of orders of magnitude. See https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yscale.html

Comment: You could try seaborn:  `sns.histplot(x=tr['exceeded_amount'], log_scale=True)`. Or `ax = sns.boxenplot(x=tr['exceeded_amount'])` followed by `ax.set_xscale('log')` to get a boxplot variant that also visualizes the distribution of the tails.

Comment: Thanks @JohanC , I updated my question with your suggestions. I would like to display the ranges for the amounts. 10^x is not very intuitive as to what amount is in that range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly set your own bin edges, and convert the x-axis to log scale:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

values = [19.0, 193.0, 4928.0, 1956.0, 171.0, 163.7, 231.0, 5.0, 878.5, 190.46, 89.0, 4.0, 35.0, 393.0, 171.0, 546.0, 99.98, 93.36, 0.82, 419.14, 181.0, 42.27, 2807.0, 116.0, 1199.0, 16.0, 128.0, 412.0, 100.0, 1070.4, 461.0, 377.0, 266.0, 930.0, 625.99, 237.5, 157.67, 58.0, 870.88, 329.5, 1418.0, 391.0, 329.0, 182.81, 329.5, 98.0, 211.0, 1.0, 557.0, 1284.04, 131.0, 113.33, 64.0, 46.66, 598.48, 149.0, 561.0, 14.83, 209.0, 454.7, 273.33, 21.0, 724.0, 2226.0, 209.0, 23.0, 853.56, 89.0, 63.25, 28.0, 41.0, 303.5, 103.82, 162.01, 1763.0, 8.0, 2359.0, 1171.0, 194.68, 1031.0, 362.0, 333.0, 312.0, 854.65, 630.0, 833.0, 691.0, 227.0, 139.47, 277.56, 1642.0, 27.0, 166.0, 931.0, 968.7, 27.33, 338.0, 201.0, 77.0, 7547.04, 0.49, 568.0, 307.07, 203.0, 167.56, 1138.78, 111.0, 51.0, 423.0, 504.62, 353.97, 51.0, 416.0, 68.05, 16.0, 7.39, 631.0, 551.0, 596.0, 89.63, 777.0, 207.0, 167.56, 246.0, 503.99, 22.0, 65.79, 21.0, 747.0, 5058.26, 1673.0, 275.92, 108.66, 99.5, 893.0, 67.0, 49.0, 663.0, 72.6, 1824.66, 127.0, 239.71, 1306.0, 815.62, 100.88, 253.0, 636.0, 600.5, 321.0, 111.0, 545.3, 312.0, 17.0, 343.61, 5933.0, 310.0, 356.0, 284.0, 139.0, 877.0, 48.95, 715.0, 126.33, 1275.0, 149.0, 8.99, 71.0, 241.0, 116.0, 225.0, 882.07, 81.0, 121.0, 53.93, 496.0, 2636.85, 71.0, 81.0, 8222.0, 52.33, 114.0, 437.0, 95.0, 28967.0, 142.0, 1.0, 1271.2, 683.76, 184.0, 220.4, 182.0, 618.0, 119.67, 661.85, 71.0, 22.37, 570.4, 388.88, 113.0, 290.0, 137.03, 3879.0, 619.0, 720.45, 961.5, 11.0, 101.0, 14.0, 1189.0, 1038.0, 246.0, 422.0, 153.4, 6999.4, 288.4, 707.28, 22681.0, 698.0, 305.0, 1097.0, 91.0, 147.0, 4793.26, 26.0, 309.0, 37.66, 59.2, 422.0, 417.13, 344.99, 29.0, 437.0, 545.0, 695.0, 39.66, 380.0, 709.1, 291.0, 1596.0, 920753.0, 115.68, 145.19, 81.0, 764.0, 751.63, 766.93, 2141.0, 327.0, 1358.3, 381.0, 115.0, 116.0, 571.0, 84.0, 697.0, 33.0, 1589.0, 123.05, 11.5, 1297.0, 71.0, 427.99, 63.0, 153.99, 197.99, 168.99, 1271.2, 30.0, 671.0, 582.33, 445.08, 378.0, 114.5, 512.0, 739.5, 411.0, 58.0, 1263.0, 436.69, 26.53, 14467.99, 1.0, 1659.82, 50.0, 103.07, 364.0, 191.2, 761.0, 225.0, 645.0, 129.0, 185.0, 22.44, 292.06, 342.4, 3347.0, 76.0, 217.5, 870.99, 54.0, 1218.0, 210.51, 111.0, 252.0, 1597.4, 123.08, 556.0, 148.0, 131.0, 356.0, 178.12, 99341.0, 422.0, 163.0, 551.0, 1992.0, 176.0, 366.0, 263.0, 156.0, 213.0, 177.0, 1095.38, 83.0, 375.32, 750.0, 203.66, 554.0, 201.72, 225.0, 267.0, 637.95, 89.0, 76.0, 189.48, 1072.21, 13.0, 284.0, 86.0, 336.99, 33.53, 117.66, 100.99, 854.0, 2985.95, 157.99, 5.01, 322.0, 51.0, 408.0, 1331.0, 312.0, 281.0, 296.18, 287.0, 197.0, 557.08, 141.0, 556.0, 16.8, 1511.36, 27.35, 225.0, 841.0, 380.0, 1211.1, 1068.11, 529.31, 4372.0, 46.0, 181.0, 225.0, 135.0, 1655.66, 3865.0, 172.0, 286.0, 143.0, 1391.0, 65.0, 76.0, 1316.0, 2419.0, 893.0, 165.0, 196.0, 15.99, 537.27, 38.0, 51.0, 380.0, 265.0, 341.0, 276.38, 135.0, 716.0, 4915.0, 59.0, 130.0, 557.08, 3178.0, 1043.8, 473.0, 1938.99, 486.0, 2272.0, 61.0, 141.27, 312.0, 252.0, 79.0, 441.0, 21.0, 71.18, 44.0, 113.0, 2294.0, 1259.0, 120.08, 881.0, 280.39, 6.0, 18.0, 42.0, 209.0, 462.0, 152.0, 301.0, 244.0, 1110.0, 149.0, 877.0, 711.0, 1978.0, 184.95, 666.0, 322.0, 205.0, 309.0, 476.0, 3178.0, 1328.0, 428.0, 183.51, 63.0, 684.0, 254.42, 354.0, 116.0, 135.0, 144.67, 31.0, 136.0, 361.0, 272.09, 737.0, 3347.0, 363.74, 506.0, 209.99, 4827.0, 545.0, 412.0, 1636.0, 96.0, 238.0, 422.0, 109.0, 44.0, 287.0, 327.99, 349.19, 28.99, 279.0, 181.0, 629.0, 137.75, 71.0, 2357.0, 493.0, 340.0, 177.16, 71.2, 4819.74, 22.0, 71.0, 73.73, 343.0, 121.0, 2272.0, 201.56, 1831.0, 158.98, 493.0, 576.8, 260.97, 847.0, 73.0, 5.0, 251.0, 207.0, 174.0, 82.86, 131.0, 1053.0, 353.0, 101.0, 854.0, 259.77, 12.37, 385.0, 9.27, 286.0, 85.0, 98.14, 21.0, 31.0, 71.0, 178.0, 63.0, 517.38, 118.0, 2350.0, 143.0, 88.0, 61.0, 297.0, 64.15, 20.56, 117.0, 189.0, 177.0, 630.0, 2997.0, 9961.0, 236.0, 240.0, 459.99, 3.0, 608.0, 341.0, 11.0, 1052.0, 42.0, 341.0, 21.0, 395.0, 575.0, 635.99, 539.83, 30.0, 570.0, 75.0, 503.99, 3774.0, 446.0, 87.0, 113.66, 217.5, 489.0, 41.0, 626.99, 461.0, 514.88, 813.99, 43.62, 1663.0, 96.0, 276.06, 73.75, 302.0, 68.0, 651.0, 25.0, 34.0]
bins = 10.0 ** np.arange(-1, 7)
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))
ax = sns.histplot(x=values, bins=bins, edgecolor='k', linewidth=2)
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xticks(bins)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
ax.ticklabel_format(axis='x', useOffset=False, style='plain')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.histplot with custom edges]

Here is a version with edges at powers of 10, multiplied by 1,2 or 5.

```py
bins = np.outer(10.0 ** np.arange(-1, 7), [1, 2, 5]).ravel()[:-2]
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))
ax = sns.histplot(x=values, bins=bins, edgecolor='k', linewidth=2)
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_xticks(bins)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda x, pos: f'{x:.1f}' if x < 1 else  f'{x:.0f}' if x < 10000 else f'{x/1000:.0f}K')
ax.margins(x=0.01)
sns.despine()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: bin edges at 1, 2 and 5 times powers of 10]

The same information can be shown as a bar plot, using np.histogram to calculate the values:

```py
bins = np.outer(10.0 ** np.arange(-1, 7), [1, 2, 5]).ravel()[:-2]
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 5))
heights, _ = np.histogram(values, bins=bins)
labels = [
    f'{x0:.1f}-{x1:.1f}' if x0 < 1 else f'{x0:.0f}-{x1:.0f}' if x0 < 10000 else f'{x0 / 1000:.0f}-{x1 / 1000:.0f}K'
    for x0, x1 in zip(bins[:-1], bins[1:])]

ax = sns.barplot(x=[lbl for lbl, h in zip(labels, heights) if h > 0], y=heights[heights > 0])
ax.margins(x=0.01)
sns.despine()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: barplot]